# Adding commas to numbers using regular expressions and find and replace

Tags: regex

I'm using Sublime Text 3 right now, working with a large .kml file.

I have hundreds of things that look like this:

```
<SimpleData name="DECPOPCNT">93971</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="DECPOPCNT">5673</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="DECPOPCNT">100971</SimpleData>
```

That I want to add commas to -- basically replacing the above with:

```
<SimpleData name="DECPOPCNT">93,971</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="DECPOPCNT">5,673</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="DECPOPCNT">100,971</SimpleData>
```

The numbers are all between 4 and 6 digits, so I basically just need to add a comma in after the hundreds digit in all cases. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex in Find what:

```
(\d)(\d{3}<)
```

And in replace statement write this:

```
$1,$2
```

Comment: You are amazing and beautiful. If anyone says otherwise, I will destroy them. Thank you.

Comment: Ha — I got distracted doodling hearts around his name in my notebook. Answer accepted, understanding of regular expressions increased.

Comment: Jajajajaja @Jesse Thanks! A pleasure help you.